# Automatic HTML page refresh preserving scroll position, working with anchors

Tags: javascript, html, page-refresh

I have a web service generating a html and I need it to be automatically refreshed in the browser every 10 seconds. I've done it simply with `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">` and it worked fine, preserving the scroll position (at least in Firefox).

Then I added some internal linking within the page, using e.g. `<a href="#foo">Foo</a>` to link to `<a name="foo"/>`. After clicking such a link, I jump to the appropriate section and `#foo` is appended to the URL in the address bar, as expected. But if the automatic refresh happens now, `#foo` disappears from the address bar and the page scrolls to the top after refresh.

Is there some way to keep automatically refreshing the page, keeping the scroll position and being able to use internal linking without breaking it all?

**UPDATE**

I've tried to change the meta to `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=page.html#foo">` (without Javascript for now, just directly this value to see if it works). I open the page as `page.html`, it refreshes once as `page.html#foo` and then it stops. Why doesn't it keep refreshing?

Comment: Why are you refreshing the entire page?

Comment: @APAD1 It's sort of a generated report/monitor thing. In principle it can change considerably between the calls.

Comment: Why not refresh the data without refreshing the entire page?

Comment: @APAD1 I'm generating a HTML document, that's what the web service returns. I know it's not ideal, but it started as simple plain text debug tool and grown into html. I don't have a service that returns the raw data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unfortunate that the whole page needs to be reloaded, and you're not able to just do an AJAX call to get the data.

Since your page needs to be refreshed every time, you could consider storing the scroll position in local storage and reading it when the page loads again. That code might look something like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    var scrollpos = localStorage.getItem('scrollpos');
    if (scrollpos) window.scrollTo(0, scrollpos);
});

window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    localStorage.setItem('scrollpos', window.scrollY);
};
```

If you would like to refresh the page and keep the anchor link, you can use JavaScript instead of a meta refresh tag:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload();
},10000);
```

Comment: This works well, thanks. The only downside is that I'm unable to use the browser _back_ function to undo the internal link jump, because the page gets refreshed without the anchor.

Comment: @Cinnam You can refresh the page keeping the anchor link if you use JavaScript - see my edit.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I just found it too, except I did `setTimeout("location.reload(true)", 10000);`. I have no Javascript experience - is that ok or should I use your way?

Comment: @Cinnam My way is a bit more standard since it doesn't rely on parsing the function out of the string. In the end it doesn't really matter, but my way is a little more common and is probably more readable to more developers. Glad I could help and thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 0):

You could try client side routing.

Eg youresite.com/path#section2

"#section2" refers to an id of your DOM element.

When ever you refresh this URL it should land you to id section2 of your DOM.

In your document.ready you could first parse the url using window.location.href and scroll to the found id.
I think this may solve your issue. :)

Comment: I'd like to scroll exactly to the last scroll position, not to the section.

Comment: On mouse scroll event you can store scroll poss to local storage and after refresh get the position from local storage and scroll . you can make this scroll event listener smart so that it wont update local storage multiple time.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing something similar (see the accepted answer), so this comment was in the right direction.